# SharePoint Web Part Gallery details of each web part

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts, object-model

When using `SPWeb.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.WebPartCatalog)`, it returns an `SPList` which of course contains a `SPListItemCollection` of the web parts in the web part gallery.

When looping through the items, is there any easy way to get properties of the web parts? Such as AllowClose, CatalogIconImageUrl, etc...

I know I can probably accomplish this using the listItem.OpenBinaryStream etc and loading the xml of the .webpart file, but I wondered if there was an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. If you load the webparts like that all you get are `SPListItem`s (which are from the gallery) and not `SPWebPart` objects (which you'll realistically only get from instances that exist on a page - or from loading in via an `SPWebPartManager` object [and even then loading from the gallery, you would need to extract the XML in exactly the same way anyway]). You'll have to do `SPListItem.File.OpenBinaryStream()` and fire it into an `XmlReader`  or `XDocument` object for easier parsing.